# Pass prop that has a dynamic name in react to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

If I have a prop that has a dynamic name, say `myProp[regNo]` where `regNo` could be a series of numbers, (in the react Dev tools, it could render as `myProp5645262` how do I pass that prop to a child?

Comment: How would you use it in the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that through `this.props` or `props` depending on if you are using class components or hooks.

Use `Object.keys(props)` to get the list of property names. Then you will be able to access the property.

This is a dummy example using hooks.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(props); // ['myProp12345', 'myProp23456', 'apple']
  const myProps = keys.filter(name => name.startsWith('myProp')) // ['myProp12345', 'myProp23456']

  // Do whatever you want here to map your values

  const myValues = myProps.map(propName => ({
    name: propName,
    value: props[propName]
  })) // [{ name: 'myProp12345', value: 'a' }, { name: 'myProp23456', value: 'b' }]
  

  return (
    <Child myValues={myValues} />
  )
}

// ...

<MyComponent myProp12345='a' myProp23456='b' apple='c' />
```

---

EDIT: After reading your question again, it seems like you wanted to pass these props to your children as is. If so:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(props); // ['myProp12345', 'myProp23456', 'apple']
  const myPropsMap = keys.reduce((map, key) => ({
    ...map,
    [key]: props[key]
  }), {}) // {myProp12345: 'a', myProp23456: 'b'}

  // Here both of the myPropXXX are passed to this child.
  return (
    <Child {...myPropsMap} />
  )
}

// ...

<MyComponent myProp12345='a' myProp23456='b' apple='c' />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ChildComponent {...props} />
```